# ServiceStack AutoQuery and Field Term Or

Tags: servicestack, autoquery-servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

I am trying to change a few fields on an autoquery to query using or (it is a search box that is searching many fields).  This doesn't seem to work although according to the documentation it should.

```
public class PropertyGet : QueryDb<DomainModel.Property>
{
    [QueryDbField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)]
    public string NameContains { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)]
    public string CityContains {get;set;}
}
```

However this does:

```
[QueryDb(QueryTerm.Or)]
 public class PropertyGet : QueryDb<DomainModel.Property>
    {
        public string NameContains { get; set; }
        public string CityContains {get;set;}
    }
```

> Changing Querying Behavior
>
> By default queries act like a filter and every condition is combined
>   with AND boolean term to further filter the result-set. This can be
>   changed to use an OR at the field-level by specifying
>   Term=QueryTerm.Or modifier, e.g:
>
> [QueryDbField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)] 
>   public string LastName { get; set; }

How can I do a field level Or query?

Comment: What do you mean by "field level Or query"? The first query needs to be a filter in a WHERE statement. What SQL are you hoping to generate?

Comment: I was only trying to filter based on or's instead of and's.  In my case, where Name contains or City contains.  There will be other fields that will have `and` conditions.  I was expecting the first case to work before I started plugging in the and conditions.

Comment: This is all in relation to a kendo grid.  The columns are filterable (AND) and there is a search box above the grid that I want to produce a set of OR conditions on the same autoquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to using a `[QueryDbField]` that relies on an [implicit convention](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#implicit-conventions) like "%Contains":

```
public class PropertyGet : QueryDb<DomainModel.Property>
{
    [QueryDbField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)]
    public string NameContains { get; set; }

    [QueryDbField(Term=QueryTerm.Or)]
    public string CityContains {get;set;}
}
```

Where when using `[QueryDbField]` you would override the implicit convention. I've changed the behavior in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/3fcb82a335dff0c686c6c3100fe4b531a8ffe528) where it now merges the behavior of both `[QueryDbField]` and the matching implicit convention so your query should now work as expected.

This change is available from v4.5.7+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: The only way I could get this to work was by specifying the entire db field defintion ` [QueryDbField(Field = "Name", Template = "{Field} LIKE {Value}", ValueFormat = "%{0}%", Term=QueryTerm.Or)]`  Just adding the `QueryTerm.Or` doesn't work for me

Comment: @lucuma oh you mean for changing the behavior to Contains, yeah if you're supplying your own `[QueryDbField]` you're taking over the behavior and need to change it from its default `=` behavior. I'll see if it's easy to retain the implicit convention behavior.

Comment: @lucuma Not how it's designed, i.e. if you use `[QueryDbField]` you're taking over complete behavior of the field so you need to specify how you want it to behave.

Comment: @lucuma FYI see updated answer where the behavior is now modified so it combines both QueryDbField and any matching implicit convention.

Comment: @lucuma no, they get deployed to NuGet - we'll deploy .NET Core early next week.